# TypoScript wrap only non-html content elements

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I still use CSS Styled Content for practicing. Now I need to wrap nothing around my content elements. I do that by

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap >
```

Around content elements that aren't of type "Pure HTML" I now need to set either a custom div or the default CSC div container.

How to achieve that in TypoScript?

Answer (score 3):

`tt_content.html.wrap` should do the job.
place it after your `tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap >`

Can be found in:

```
typo3/sysext/css_styled_content/static/setup.txt
```